# Angular - Add Auth Interceptor Only On Lazy Loaded Module

Tags: angular

i have 3 modules. app, reports and connect.

To access the reports module you need to have a jwt so i have an auth interceptor to handle this. Currently the interceptor is defined in my **app.module.ts** but i only want the auth interceptor to be used in my lazy loaded **reports.module.ts**

**Current Setup.**

> app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';
import { CoreModule } from './core/core.module';

import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AuthInterceptor } from './core/interceptors/auth.interceptor';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        SharedModule,
        CoreModule.forRoot(),
    ],
     providers: [{ provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AuthInterceptor, multi: true },
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**New Setup**

> app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';
import { CoreModule } from './core/core.module';

import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        SharedModule,
        CoreModule.forRoot(),
    ],

    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

> reports.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { UpperCasePipe } from '@angular/common';
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
import { TitleCasePipe } from '@angular/common';

import { ReportsRoutingModule } from './reports-routing.module';

import { ReportsComponent } from './reports.component';

import { SharedModule } from './../shared/shared.module';
...

import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AuthInterceptor } from './../core/interceptors/auth.interceptor';


@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        SharedModule,
        ReportsRoutingModule,
        HttpClientModule,
    ],
    declarations: [
       ...
    ],
    entryComponents: [
      ...,

    ],
    providers: [DatePipe, UpperCasePipe, TitleCasePipe, { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AuthInterceptor, multi: true }],

})
export class ReportsModule { }
```

However, the new setup does not work and the auth interceptor never gets fired. ( i even tried commenting out HTTPClientModule import from reports).

Comment: if you want to Auth interceptor to work only to lazy loaded module then you have to import HttpClientModule in lazy loaded module. But in that case only interceptor provided in that lazy module works for that particular module, means no interceptor provided outside of that lazy module works for that lazy module.

Comment: @RaviSevta you can see from my code above i have imported a HttpClientModule in reports.module but still did not work

Comment: your provided code seems like okay, so to debug your problem i need a running demo code, so can you provide it by some online tools like stackblitz etc.